# Como corrigir problema de encoding em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou executando o código abaixo:

```
alert('Não é possível realizar essa operação sem a seleção de uma banca.');
```

mas está aparecendo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema não é o encode do JavaScript, e sim o da página. Tente usar `<meta charset="utf-8" />` na sua seção `head`:

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Use essa tag logo após a abertura do `head`, antes mesmo do `title`. Dependendo do estágio do seu projeto e de como ele foi configurado, pode ser que o charset não seja `utf-8`, e sim `iso-8859-1`

Answer (score 5):

Verifique em seu editor de texto ou ide, qual o tipo de codificação padrão para arquivos novos, após verificado você verá que deve ser **UTF-8** ou **iso-8859-1** (também chamado de Windows-1252 as vezes). Se o arquivo já existir, você pode verificar a codificação através do rodapé no **Notepad++**.

Use a meta tag para cada caso:

**html5**

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

**html4.x**

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Você deve usar UTF-8 ou iso-8859-1

Answer (score 4):

Quando isso ocorre:

1. Abro o arquivo no Notepad++ e faço a conversão para `UTF-8`
2. Me certifico que a página possui o header `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Resolve em 90% dos casos.